# UISplitViewController, reuse DetailViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

**Setup:** Create a boilerplate iOS Master-Detail app in Xcode and run it. Everytime you click on a master item it re-creates the detailVC and configures it to display the new data.

**Premise:** Often this is what I want, but other times it does little more than change the text in a single label. Doesn't it make more sense to re-use the existing DetailVC? (at least in this case)

So what's the best way to do this?

**Contemplation:** When I look at the boilerplate code I see the MasterVC creates class scoped var for the detailVC.

```
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
```

It sets this value in `viewDidLoad`, but it then never uses it for anything. Huh? In `prepare(for:sender:)` we get this code

```
let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
```

which creates a new instance of the `DetailViewController`. If you put a break point in after it's created and compare it to the class var `detailViewController` you can see they are different.

The `UIStoryboardSegue` is creating my new `DetailViewController` which can easily be confirmed by looking at the documentation.

> You do not create segue objects directly. Instead, the storyboard
>   runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view
>   controllers.

I could remove the segue on row select and manually call the method on my detailVC  and that's probably the easiest, but segues are so purty and visual in IB. I could could probably create a custom segue. What else could I do and is there a clear "best" way?

Answer (score 1):

First remove the `var detailViewController` that is a remnant from when the template was using `UINavigationController` and won't work with the `UISplitViewController` because if a new master is init when collapsed, say after a selection in a root VC then it isn't possible to find the previous detail. iOS 14 added a new method to easily find the previous detail even if the split is currently collapsed, [viewController(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/3580917-viewcontroller) and you could use it like this:

```
// only perform when collapsed, otherwise find the detail and update it's item.
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier != "showDetail" { return true }
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return true }
    guard let svc = splitViewController else { return true }
    if svc.isCollapsed { return true }
    
    let secondaryViewController = svc.viewController(for: .secondary)
    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController,
    let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return true }
    
    let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    topAsDetailController.detailItem = object
    
    return false // cancels the segue
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this question, here is my solution until someone comes up with something better.

Go to Interface Builder and remove the `showDetail` segue which goes from the master tableview to the detailVC. Then go into the MasterViewController class and remove the `prepare(for:sender:)` function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new function in Table View area (this new function is part of `UITableViewDelegate`)

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     detailViewController?.detailItem = object
}
```